# Question changed - answer doesn't match question, but does match subject

Tags: discussion

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830207/) recently. It originally mentioned some issues with IFFT, but mostly appeared to be focused on wrapping numbers to the +/-pi range because they thought that was the solution to the problem.

I gave an answer mentioning the builtin MATLAB function to do it and how to implement it if that toolkit isn't available. However, in discussion in the answer's comments I realized that the OP was having a different issue and the wrapping was a red herring. I had them update the question, and in the comments on the question we worked out what was actually going on.

Now my answer has nothing to do with the actual question, but it still matches the wrapping mentioned in the question title, and I feel it would be a useful answer for someone wanting to wrap phase angles.

Should I just delete the answer at this point because it no longer matches the updated question? The updated question has some problems - I'm not sure it will be helpful to other users at all. Should the whole thing be deleted at this point?

Comment: Sounds like the question title needs to be updated to match the question if the question has been significantly changed.

Answer (score 5):

If you misunderstood the question and ended up posting an answer that contains useful content, but is not in fact an answer to the question, then you should delete it.  We want to have answers that *answer the question*.

If you consider the content useful and feel that it should be preserved, then you can ask a new question that asks the question that your answer answers, and then post your answer to that question.

As always when self answering questions, keep in mind that the question and answer will be evaluated for quality independently, and each needs to be up to the same quality standards as every other post on the site.  For a case like this, you shouldn't be just posting a throw-away question that's just a placeholder for your answer, but rather asking a quality question that you would want to see someone else ask (if they didn't know the answer).

Comment: It's not that I misunderstood the question - the question originally asked specifically how to do what I explained in my answer, and mentioned that they needed to know how in order to solve a specific problem. It was in the discussion afterwards where it became clear that it wouldn't actually solve the problem they were having. It also answers the question that is still in the title. I do like the self-answering idea - if the discussion here doesn't suggest anything better I'll probably accept this then delete and self-answer.

Comment: @Katie If the user asked a question and then later realized that they meant to ask a different question, it's inappropriate of them to edit the question and change it to be a different question.  They should be asking a new question if they have a different question to ask.

Comment: @Katie: If you see something like that, just revert it, unless there are no answers.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I don't have rollback privileges yet - it looks like that starts at 2k. I'd appreciate it if you (or someone else here) takes care of it because I can't. If no one reverts it by tomorrow then I'll probably flag for a moderator to take a look at it like I saw suggested in a meta thread on rolling back. Revision 2 is the question I answered.